# Ruby rails gem bundle install fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to set up a new project with ruby rails but when I try to do `bundle install`. It gives me this error.

> ```
> An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> In Gemfile:
>   sqlite3
> ```

Comment: could be your bundler version??

Comment: Bundler version 2.3.21

Comment: Do you get `sqlite3` and `sqlite3-devel`( defends on your OS ) installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install sqlite3 and sqlite3-dev first.

```
sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

and after try again in your project

```
bundle install
```